# is there such a thing as JSX 'partials'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js, jsx

I work mainly with Handlebars JS now, but I am looking at JSX. Is there a JSX equivalent to Handlebars partials? I want to know if I can create small bits of markup that I can reuse in several different JSX views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't provide partials. Some things about React:

- React doesn't provide any notion of partials. The fundamental, atomic unit of React is the **component**.
- Instead of passing a partial, you'd create a component or components and re-use those. Even better than a partial because it's a function, so it's encapsulated **and** testable!
- If the markup is small, it should probably either be moved up into a parent component or down into a simpler one

Generally, my rule of thumb is that components should follow the principle of single responsibility or separation of concerns. If something doesn't seem to fit into a component, you've likely got problems in the other two components and could reconsider them, too :)

Another couple rules of thumb to go by when thinking about components:

- code smells should usually end up as components (repeating something over and over again, etc.)
- components are usually either presentational or containerized. The latter have roles in the props/state tree for an app (you never "see them")
- refactor things into components as you need to; don't start out encapsulating everything, because you may have prematurely refactored and created more problems for yourself
- the most reusable and decoupled components are like the best functions or objects: clean, flexible, testable, and they do address a single concern
- at the same time, don't go crazy and turn **everything** into a component. i.e. you don't (usually) want:

  `<Letter>R</Letter><Letter>e</Letter><Letter>a</Letter><Letter>c</Letter><Letter>t</Letter>`

Here's an incredibly simple example:

```
'use strict';

const OuterComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
        <div>Outer{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
});

const ReusableComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
        <div>Am I reusable? {this.props.reusable && 'Yeah!' }</div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <OuterComponent>
    <ReusableComponent reusable={true}/>
  </OuterComponent>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Will render:

```
OuterComponent
Am I reusable? Yeah!
```

Note, though, that using `creatClass` provides you more than you might need if you're not working with mutable state (which is provided to you within the component via `this.state`), you can easily use what are sometimes called "stateless functional components" (because they are, well, stateless and returned by functions). These could easily be arrow functions implicitly returning the JSX (which is essentially just `React.createElement()` generator)

```
const OuterComponent = (props) => <div>Outer{this.props.children}</div>;

const ReusableComponent = (props) => <div>Am I reusable? {this.props.reusable && 'Yeah!' }</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <OuterComponent>
    <ReusableComponent reusable={true}/>
  </OuterComponent>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just create a [component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) for that. Components can be as simple or as complex as you want them to be.

Example:

```
function Badge(props) {
    return <span className="badge">{props.counter}</span>
}
```

With a corresponding `.badge` CSS class, this could be a very simply component that renders as a red circle with a number, and is used as `<Badge counter={42} />`.

Comment: As @markthethomas explains in his answer (sort of), components aren't a complete solution, because, with, for example, ERB partials, you can have code that is inserted into the effective `render()` method. In your example, one partial might be `<span className="badge">{yield}</span>`. This would allow someone to actually place _different_ components within other components and simply render one another inline. With React, this would be fairly tricky and involve passing of `props` containing additional components.